Does <apex:outputText> as any character limitation
Does <apex:outputText value="some text"> as any character limitation? Can it accommodate text up to 32k characters?

Visualforce itself has a limitation of 15MB of output, though in practice, you'll find the 6MB heap limit will likely define the maximum merge value. Here's an example outputting a string that is 400,000 characters long:
public class outputBigString {
    public String getBigText() {
        return 'ABC\n'.repeat(100000);
    }
}

<apex:page controller="outputBigString">
    <apex:outputText value="{!bigText}" />
</apex:page>

I also tested providing an attribute value directly in the Visualforce page:
<apex:outputText value="
 **literally hundreds of thousands of characters**
" />

And it displayed without any errors.

What about viewstate? Is not that 135kb?

@kurunve The view state doesn't apply here, because we're not storing data in the view state; only non-transient, non-static, serializable variables count towards that limit. The only hard limit you'll find is the 15MB maximum response size.
